# Pass an object as a global variable in js from gs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, global-variables

I am working with Google Apps Script to build a web application.
I have a function in google app script:

```
function getPalette(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws_palette = ss.getSheetByName("palette");
  var palette_data = ws_palette.getRange(2,1,1,1).getValue();
  var palette = JSON.parse(palette_data.replace(/'/g, '"'));
  return palette;
}
```

I want to pass this `palette` object to javascript.html as a global variable.

How can I do that? Many thanks!

Comment: Please add more details, what is gs?

Comment: What do you mean by  "universal"  variable?

Comment: @TheMaster means I can use it in every function everywhere in the javascript file

Comment: @GwenYang Still unclear.  Everywhere in Js file or gs file? What do you mean everywhere? Have you tried templates and google.script.run? Were those not satisfactory? If so why?

Comment: Are you talking about an `html` file located in the same project like the `code.gs` file?

Comment: @ziganotschka yes exactly. sorry for the confusions

Answer (score 2):

### Apps Script side variables are accessible from the html/javascript side by [scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#scriptlets)

Scriptlets allow you to run any Apps Script code with `<? ... ?>` or access any variable from `code.gs` with `<?= ... ?>` within the `html` or `javascript` part or your WebApp.

**Sample for accessing global variables:**

*Code.gs*

```
const globalVar = "I am global";

function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("javascript").evaluate();
}
```

*javascript.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
    console.log(<?= globalVar ?>);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Important:**

Apps Script scriptlets will only work if you return your html content by creating and evaluating a template rather than directly creating an output.

Comment: thank you! I think this is very close. I used `function include_JS() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("Javascript").getContent();
}` and have the function in the question in .gs file. then `const palette = getPalette();`. then in Javascript.html I used `let palette = <? palette ?>` it didn't work.

Comment: Please read the last phrase in my answer: create and evaluate a template instead of directly creating an output, so:`createTemplateFromFile("javascript").evaluate();` instead of `createHtmlOutputFromFile("Javascript")`